# How to install programs as admin in Powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-scripting

I started to write a powershell script to automate the deployment of new Windows 10 PCs.

I've done a script to install the corporate apps and mapping the network folders and printers.

But I have a problem that I must input the admin password for each program I wish to install.

I've searched the internet and all I found was the `runas` command, I see that is similar to the `su` of Linux but I can't push the password.

This is how I made the install of all applications:

```
Set-Content "$DESTINO\program.bat" -value 'msiexec -i C:\progtemp\program.msi /quiet'
Start-Process $DESTINO\program.bat -Wait
```

Do you know a better method?

Comment: have you tried storing the creds in a $Var? use the `Get-Credential` cmdlet to do that ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

The two main ways to run something as an admin automated are as follows:

1. Create a Scheduled task to run a script, you can choose to run this escalated and store the credentials as required
2. Create a startup script using powershell (or batch file if you must!)
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dn789190(v=ws.11)

Startup scripts run as the user system which is the highest privilege possible. Be aware that network access may not be available at startup and some things may not be accessible to system on your local network etc.

Highly recommend looking at Chocolatey https://www.chocolatey.org and possibly boxstarter: https://boxstarter.org/
to get you started with some automation and package management.

Microsoft also have a similar technology in early stages:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/package-manager/

But frankly Chocolatey is an open framework and its well established and mature at this stage.